# Android - Not auto select an EditText field

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

When I travel between Activities my app auto select the first EditText field on the screen, calling the keyboard.

There is any way to start an Activity without selecting anything by default?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should add this to its parent layout

`android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`